# What is a cast-iron schedule?

Tags: vocabulary

In *[The Riddle of the Sands](https://www.gutenberg.org/files/2360/2360-h/2360-h.htm#chap01)* (1903), Erskine Childers writes:

> For the plain truth was that my work was neither interesting nor
> important, and consisted chiefly at present in smoking cigarettes, in
> saying that Mr So-and-So was away and would be back about 1st October,
> in being absent for lunch from twelve till two, and in my spare
> moments making *précis* of—let us say—the less confidential consular
> reports, and squeezing the results into **cast-iron schedules**.

> That day I made my last *précis* and handed over my **schedules**—Procrustean
> beds, where unwilling facts were stretched

What is a *cast-iron schedule*? I have Googled for definitions and documents containing the locution, to no avail. I don't think the locution is being used figuratively and can only venture that it refers to a type of binder used in government offices (the British Foreign Office in this case) at the beginning of the 20th century.

EDIT: I have discovered the concept of [Retention Schedule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Retention_schedule) for archival. Possibly this is what Childers means here and possibly it refers by extension to an archive document format with strict rules, especially with regard to text length, hence *cast iron*.

Comment: Did you consider the definition of cast-iron as an [idiom](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/cast-iron)?

Comment: @KillingTime I did and rejected the figurative sense because the idea of putting reports inside timetables does not make sense and because cast-iron in the figurative sense would imply an emphasis that the narratîve does not support. This is just a casual description of a task that is peripheral to the narrative.

Comment: Schedule is also 'written document' as per MW https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/schedule, where it is flagged as 'obsolete', but if the book is from 1903 it might fit. The first paragraph describes a very repetitive work, so the idiom mentioned by KillingTime can be a good fit too, describing documents that were unlikely to change.

Comment: If _cast-iron_ is not used figuratively here, aren't we left with only the literal sense (3%C, 97%Fe say)? How can this make sense? Are you aiming for 'Perhaps the whole string _cast-iron schedule_ is an idiom, a single lexeme?'? // You need to show more details of research (have you tried CED, Lexico, AHD, M-W, Collins, RHK Webster's, Wiktionary ...?)

Answer (score 5):

Significantly, cast iron is one of the least-ductile of metals.  That is, it is very stiff, and if you try to bend it, it breaks.  Cast iron must be cast (formed) into its final shape while it is molten metal, whereas metals like aluminum, copper, or even normal iron-based steel can be bent or "formed" to some extent while at room temperature.

So, anything that is "cast-iron" cannot be bent, and saying a schedule is "cast-iron" is saying "You ain't gonna change it, baby."  A more familiar idiom with the same meaning is "cast in concrete".

I'll note that "schedule" is used in manufacturing to refer to specific specifications.  For instance: https://www.metalsupermarkets.com/what-do-pipe-schedules-mean/

Whether this meaning is alluded to in the original quotation is hard to say, though.

Comment: This is basic, and doesn't address the archaic/obsolete sense of 'schedule'.

Answer (score -1):

The use of *cast-iron* is an idiomatic analogy.

> Schedule = noun
> Legal Definition of schedule
> 1a : a list or statement of supplementary details appended to another document
> b : a formal list, table, catalog, or inventory
> 2 : a plan that indicates the time and sequence of each element
>
> [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/schedule)

Although meanings of *schedule* usually pertain to the listing of planned activities, Merriam Webster here (meaning 1b.) illustrates its use as a mere list. In diplomatic matters, the record of minor events such as came to the attention of the writer would be compiled by him and would become the formal record. As such, the events, their timing and their sequence would become a matter of bureaucratic record. This would lead to the record’s becoming rigid and immutable, as is cast iron.

The reference to the Procrustean bed may be understood to refer to the distorting way in which accounts of complex human activities must be fitted into the constraining formal structures of diplomatic bureaucratic record. This use reinforces the viewpoint that I advance in my previous paragraph.

> Procrustean = : marked by arbitrary often ruthless disregard of individual differences or special circumstances
>
> [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/procrustean)

Comment: I didn't downvote but I could hazard a guess as to the *why* of it— It would save the reader a lot of trouble if you had cut to the chase like @Hot Licks has done. I am not comparing, but you surely have tried to gild the lily here.

Comment: I would have downvoted had not two people already done so. (1) for answering a question where M-W gives a clear answer but _no research is **shown**_ and (2) for choosing the wrong sense. I've upvoted Grand Torini's _comment_.

Comment: @user405662 You may be right; I might even sympathize. But who knows until the condemnatory ones come clean about their motives? On other occasions we are criticized for over-brief answers. There is sometimes too much of a feeling of Venetian denunciation rather than collaborative explanation about this site.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth What wrong sense do you refer to?

Comment: M-W sense 4b is the one that is almost certainly correct.

Comment: Weird. Where has 1b gone? My enemies have been at M-W. Oh well, Happy Christmas to all.